# Can i use "if and only if" and "then and only then" in the same sentence for emphasis?

Tags: emphasis

I want to be crystal clear and add much emphasis that something will happen *if and only if* a specific condition is met. I thought of *If and only if* and *then and only then*.

Can i use **both** in the same sentence to give emphasis to the condition that must be met?

Example:
"**If and only if** you are wearing your spacesuit, **then and only then** <s>can</s> may you exit the spacecraft."

Would a native speaker express in such a way to give emphasis or that would sound unfamiliar in English?

Comment: (i hope i will get an answer from a native speaker, NASA wants their door sign ASAP!)

Comment: "then and only then" would need to continue ... "can you exit". In my head, at least...

Comment: @Catija fixed! thanks! well anybody, feel free to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that it's OK. There's no grammatical rule that says you can't do this. I'm guessing that I've seen it done before - though I'd guess it's done more for comedic effect than in a serious way. I'm also pretty sure that I've seen someone say it in a comedic film, too.

I might make the suggestion to set off the "and only then" with an em dash or commas... this will make the stress of "and only then" even stronger.

> If – and only if – you are wearing your space suit, then – and only then – may you exit the space craft.

If you really want to make it official, you'll want to use "may" not "can"... they certainly *can* leave the space craft without a space suit but it wouldn't be a smart idea.

Comment: In suitable atmosphere, leaving without spacesuit wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You can, sure, but the distinction is redundant. At least in mathematical logic, ["iff" is used alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) for the equivalence relation. If the condition is vital, the repetition might distract from the message.

After all, **if and only if** is redundant, already.

Comment: strangely redundant? my goal is to give emphasis. would a native speaker express in such a way to give emphasis or that would sound unfamiliar in English? In my native language it sounds pretty normal but i have doubts about this in English, hence the question :/

Comment: I wouldn't know, I am not a native speaker. Haven't heard it though and I guess that's because it interrupts the flow of speech.

Comment: On the other hand, it might be the logical next step after **if and only if**, which is already redundant compared to only **only if**.